# Android API is not working

Tags: android, api, android-studio

Android studio is not working correctly and sent picture of problem please check and provide a feasible solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change your minSDK in your gradle file to 19. I seems like your project can only support API22 and above atm.

Comment: What about `disable the instant run`.

Comment: Problem 1 is solved by changing minSdkVersion as you said but problem 2nd is as it is (shown in 2nd image)

Answer (score -1):

Go to your `build.gradle(app)` file and look for `minSdkVersion`. Change its value from 22 to 18. This happened because your phone has API 19 and minSdk of your app is 22.

Comment: Problem 1 is solved by changing minSdkVersion as you            said but problem 2nd is as it is (shown in 2nd image)

Comment: Just uninstall the previous APK and click ok or you can mark this answer as accepted and ask another question for the next problem.

Comment: Done that but nothing happened

Comment: Try to debug in some other device.